# Pointlike function without minimum.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Find a pointlike function that does not attain its minimum value. Deduce that it's not of the type $u:x\mapsto \delta_z(x)+k$ where $z\in X$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

The problem is from the book "Metric Spaces" from the author Micheal Searcoid.

My effort: In the metric space $(X,e)$, where $e$ is the usual metric, we produce the function $u:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, with $u(x)=|x|=e(x,0)=\delta_0(x)$.

$u$ does not get the minimum value which is $0$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: what is $X$ in your attempt? what is $0$ in $e(x, 0)$?

Comment: What is a "pointlike function"?

Comment: What if $X$ is a general space? Does it change something? Regardless of that let's say $X=\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: Still wonder what's a pointliike function.

Comment: If $X=\mathbb{R}^+$ then $0 \in X$ fails, so it seems $e(0,x)$ not defined.

Comment: What is that delta thing?

Answer (score 2):

Let (S,d) be an unbounded metric space.
Assume a in S.
Define f(x) = 1/d(a,x) if x /= a, = 1 otherwise.

Does f have a minimum?
Does g(x) = -d(a,x) have a minimum?

Let S be infinite and A = { x(n) : n in N } subset S.
Define f:S -> R, f(x(n)) = 1/n, f(x) = 1 if x not in A.
Does this f have a minimum?

For a surprise, consider the case when S is finite.

Comment: In your first example where is $0$? if $x=a$ we get $1$ and if $x \ne a$ we get the formula above. So $f$ is unbounded and does not get its minimum.

Comment: @argiriskar.  0 is a lower bound for f.